# How do I check the availability of a url?

Tags: ruby

How do I know if the response for a url is 200 or 404 and how do I check the availability of the url?

Comment: Simply look at the server's response... There's a lot of information missing in this question. What is it you're doing exactly in this situation? Please provide some concrete situation for us to have a look at. For example, provide us with some code that shows a request which you would want to have status code recognition. Also, please try doing some research for yourself, and tell us what you've found so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a GET request using [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html):

```
uri = URI('http://example.com/index.html')
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

puts res.code
```